# Typescript error Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am doing my NextJS app with Typescript enabled , here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false, // Set this to true for checking new files
    "noImplicitAny": false, // Set this to true for checking new files
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "@/icons/*": ["ui/icons/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out", "cypress"]
}
```

here is my next.config.js

```
const NextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  images: {
    path: `https://${customImageOptimizationDomain}/_next/image`,
    domains: allowedExternalDomainsForImage,
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  },
}

const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})

const nextConfigHOC = nextTranslate(withBundleAnalyzer(NextConfig))

module.exports = nextConfigHOC
```

When I check for error during my commit using

```
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "tsc --noEmit"
    ]
  },
```

I get two types of error

- `ui/features/navbar/signout.tsx(27,7): error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.`
- `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/icons/navbar/logout.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I am not getting error in VScode but during commit , any reason please HELP!!!

I don't want to see these error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
"tsc --noEmit --jsx"

Comment: What about the type declaration error